# Store a value in an array inside one for loop

Tags: python, string, for-loop

I would like to store each value of price in an array, getting it from a dict. I am a fresh at python, I spent hours trying to figure this out...

```
for item in world_dict:
     if item[1] == 'House':
       price = float(item[2])
       print p

The output is like:
200.5
100.7
300.9
...
n+100
```

However, I want to store it on this format : [200.5, 100.7, 300.9, ..., n+100]

Comment: You just want the values? like `word_dict.values()`?

Comment: @ssm this is what is a bit strange about the iteration. If `world_dict` is a dict, then the OP iterates over keys, which are tuples, according to the output.

Comment: @alecxe I didn't know that you could store multiple values with the same key in a dictionary. So if `House` is a key, then isnt he just wanting to do `word_dict['Hoise']`? I am a little confused ... :(

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Define a [list](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) and append to it:

```
prices = []
for item in world_dict:
     if item[1] == 'House':
       price = float(item[2])
       prices.append(price)

print(prices)
```

or, you can write it in a shorter way by using [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
prices = [float(item[2]) for item in world_dict if item[1] == 'House']
print(prices)
```

Comment: I appreciate your help very much. Thank you. It was exactly I was looking ofr

Answer (score 0):

This a simple example of how to store values into an array using for loop in python
Hope this will help freshers to gain something when they search the above question

```
list = [] #define the array 

#Fucntion gets called here
def gameConfiguration():
n= int(input("Enter Number of Players : "))
    for i in range(0, n): 
        ele = (input("Name : ")) 
        list.append(ele) # adding the element to the array
    
    print(list[0]) #so you can print the element 1 
    print(list[1]) #so you can print the element 2 so on and soforth

gameConfiguration() # starts the execution of the fuction
```

Answer (score 0):

In simplest way, to store the value of for loop in array.

```
from array import *

ar = []

for i in range (0, 5, 1) :

    x = 3.0*i+1
    
    ar.append(x)
    
print(ar)
```

Output like this;

```
[1.0, 4.0, 7.0, 10.0, 13.0]
```